# Android - set image to imageview for user profile

Tags: java, android

i have an app that get picture from gallery and display into ImageView.
i want the image to stay. when a user select image from gallery or camera i want the image to set as profile.the problem i have is when image selected and display, if i reopen the app the image is gone it does not say.i know i could you url but i dont want like that. whether SharedPreference , Bitmap catch or string64 i dont know. i'm feeling dump now i couldn't solve and couldn't find any example. i searched a lot but i couldn't find.

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I understand your requirement as to persist the profile image. Basically you can get the image from gallery and store it in your app storage. So next time, you open the app you can get the image from storage.